# Using scikit-learn LinearRegression to plot a linear fit

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, curve-fitting

I am trying to make linear regression model that predicts the son's length from his father's length

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


Headings_cols = ['Father', 'Son']
df = pd.read_csv('http://www.math.uah.edu/stat/data/Pearson.txt', 
                 delim_whitespace=True, names=Headings_cols)



X = df['Father']  
y = df['Son']  

model2 = LinearRegression()
model2.fit(y, X)

plt.scatter(X, y,color='g')
plt.plot(X, model.predict(X),color='g')

plt.scatter(y, X, color='r')
plt.plot(y, X, color='r')
```

I get error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Father'
```

The second thing is calculating the average length of the sons, and the standard error of the mean ?

Comment: In which line of the code do you get that error?

Comment: X = df['Father']  
y = df['Son']

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two main issues here:

1. Getting the data out of the source
2. Getting the data into the shape that [`sklearn.LinearRegression.fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) understands

**1. Getting the data out**
The source file contains a header line with the column names. We do not want to column names in our data, so after reading in the whole data into the dataframe `df`, we can tell it to use the first line as headers by
`df.head()`. This allows to later query the dataframe by the column names as usual, i.e. `df['Father']`.

**2. Getting the data into shape**
The [`sklearn.LinearRegression.fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit) takes two arguments. First the "training data", which should be a 2D array, and second the "target values". In the case considered here, we simply what to make a fit, so we do not care about the notions too much, but we need to bring the first input to that function into the desired shape. This can be easily done by creating a new axis to one of the arrays, i.e. `df['Father'].values[:,np.newaxis]`

**The complete working skript:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_csv('http://www.math.uah.edu/stat/data/Pearson.txt',
                 delim_whitespace=True)
df.head() # prodce a header from the first data row


# LinearRegression will expect an array of shape (n, 1) 
# for the "Training data"
X = df['Father'].values[:,np.newaxis]
# target data is array of shape (n,) 
y = df['Son'].values


model2 = LinearRegression()
model2.fit(X, y)

plt.scatter(X, y,color='g')
plt.plot(X, model2.predict(X),color='k')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed answer, helped me with my same issue. I just didn't fully understand the shaping of the data but I've made the respective edits and it's works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the answer to the same question, but the initial dataset URL is no longer valid.  The "Father/Son" Pearson height dataset csv can be retrieved from the following URL and then just needs a couple of minor tweaks to work as advertised (note the renaming of the .csv file):

http://www.randomservices.org/random/data/Pearson.html

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import csv

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# data retrieved from http://www.randomservices.org/random/data/Pearson.html#

df = pd.read_csv('./pearsons_height_data.csv',
                 quotechar='"',
                 quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

df.head() # produce a header from the first data row

# LinearRegression will expect an array of shape (n, 1)
# for the "Training data"
X = df['Father'].values[:,np.newaxis]
# target data is array of shape (n,)
y = df['Son'].values

model2 = LinearRegression()
model2.fit(X, y)

plt.scatter(X, y,color='g')
plt.plot(X, model2.predict(X),color='k')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

When loading the data, do this instead:

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://www.math.uah.edu/stat/data/Pearson.txt', 
                 delim_whitespace=True)
df.columns = Headings_cols
```

You should also make sure X is shaped correctly:

```
X = df['Father'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Comment: It gives this error ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [   1 1078]

Comment: Looks like you might be feeding the data in backwards. Try `model2.fit (X, y)`

Comment: @AlexG The problem is related to the way `LinearRegression.fit` expects it's data input. So reshaping or reversing the order of elements does not help. One needs to add a new dimension to the first input array as shown in my solution.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest that is why I included this line in my solution (a couple days ago): `X = df['Father'].values.reshape(-1, 1)`